# NullReferenceException throws StackOverflowException

Tags: c#-4.0, exception

I have a case where the application is throwing a `NullReferenceException` which switch off my application throwing a `StackOverflowException`.

The first exception is logical and I understand it. It is not user-handled and I'm expecting to go to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

But no, a `StackOverflowException` is fired immediatly after the `NullReferenceException` and my application is shut down.

I don't understand the reason of the `StackOverflowException` because the biggest stack on  call stacks at this moment isn't huge (~15 rows).

The particularity of the situation is that I'm in a delegate which is subscribed to  `VisibleChanged` event handler of a control.

Here are a sample reproducing the problem.

```cs
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VisibleChanged += Function();
    }

    private EventHandler Function()
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    }
```

In fact , when i was doing the sample , i think i got the issue. Throwing an exception in the event Visible Changed seem to change the visibility and there is a recursive call ( that i strangely can't see) who involveld a stackoverflow.. But i don 't understand why i can't see it.

Comment: Can you psot some code around which you get this error?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without code to look at, so please post some relevant code. Note that Stack Overflow Exceptions usually point to problems with recursion (functions that call themselves or functions that call each other, in an endless sequence).

Comment: Are you trying to change the Visible property again in your delegate, making your event handler fire recursively?

Comment: No, i provided a sample in the main article.